# При получении списка изображений из WebView Android адреса выводятся некоректно

Tags: javascript, android, изображения, android-webview

Получаю из `WebView` Android список изображений с помощью `document.images`. 
Список то получаю, но вот пути к изображениям получаются с двумя лишними `//`.

Например, в `WebView` у меня изображение с путем:

```
file:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/MyFolder/JPEG_20181211_145525_1429883720.jpg
```

Но если провести запрос на список изображений, то в списке выводит:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/MyFolder/JPEG_20181211_145525_1429883720.jpg
```

Использую такой код для получения строки со всеми изображениями из WebView:

```
private void getAllImagesAsStringFromWebView() {

        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function getSelectionText() {" +
                " var img = document.images, s='';" +
                " for(i=0; i<img.length; i++)" +
                "    if(i==(img.length-1)){" +
                "       s+=img[i].src;" +
                "    }else{" +
                "       s+=img[i].src+ ',';" +
                "    }" +
                " android.getListImages (s);" +
                "})();");
    }
```

Так вывожу список

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public void getListImages(String listImages) {

          System.out.println("img = " + listImages);

    }
```

Это на Андроид 7.0.

Может есть какой то другой способ получить список изображений, который не извращается над адресами?

Comment: Они не лишние, так и должно быть - это правильный `URI`. Посмотрите на адресную строку браузера: там тоже два слэша (`https://`) и третий в начале пути после домена. У локального файла нет домена, поэтому в его адресе три слэша подряд.

Comment: @woesss В ранних версиях андроида пути были с одним слешем, сейчас они с 3-мя. Вроде так. Но дело в том что у меня в вебвью заливается фото  в котором путь к фото имеет 1-н слэш. Если я открываю HTML вариант этого вебвью, то там путь с 1-м слешем. Вот его то я и пытался получитьс помощью "document.images". А он почему-то выдает результат выборки, но у путей уже 3 слеша.